# Unable to save and exit an editor

Tags: linux, ubuntu, crontab

I open new window by typing `crontab -e` in terminal. After that I placed this line at the bottom.

```
0 5 * * * /home/myname/scripts/do-every-day.sh
```

But I cannot save and exit by pressing `Esc`, `:wq` and `enter`!
 I type `Esc`, then `:`, I get **Unknown command**. Then I type `wq`, the wq display beside `.sh`. When press enter it goes to new line!!!

Comment: You are **not** opening the file with the **vi**sual editor: you are using the *nano* editor. If you wish to open the crontab file with *vi*, issue: *EDITOR=vi crontab -e*. To double-check, try: *nano some-file*, you will see the same layout you saw earlier with *crontab*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. As I'm opening the nano editor, in order to save, it is not using `:wq`. Instead, it use `ctrl+x`(exit) and it will ask you to save. Press Y to save.

Comment: You are **not** opening the file with the **vi**sual editor: you are using the *nano* editor. If you wish to open the crontab file with *vi*, issue: *EDITOR=vi crontab -e*. To double-check, try: *nano some-file*, you will see the same layout you saw earlier with *crontab*.